# Extremely slow internet on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: internet

I've recently switched to Ubuntu, and I've done some playing around a bit, but can't seem to fix the internet being slow... I usually get around 100 Mbps+ on a speed test on Windows but on Ubuntu I only get around 35 Mbps max. I've tried a bunch of commands in terminal but can't seem to fully fix the issue.

Output for `sudo lshw | grep -A 15 "network"`:

```
 *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlp1s0
                version: 00
                serial: b0:fc:36:b8:d0:61
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=5.3.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.169 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:44 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b03fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
--
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: enp2s0
                version: 10
                serial: 8c:16:45:f5:ca:07
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
                resources: irq:35 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:f0a04000-f0a04fff memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
```

Comment: Related: [Internet speed Doubles with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1163961/968501)

Comment: More information is needed: for example, what's the type of your network adapter? Add the output of `sudo lshw | grep -A 15 "network"` via an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1222075/edit) to the question.

Comment: There, I put the output.